# Hadoop cluster with docker swarm

Tags: hadoop, networking, docker, hdfs

I'm trying to setup a hadoop cluster inside a docker swarm with multiple hosts, with a datanode on each docker node with a mounted volume.I made some tests and works fine, but the problem comes when a datanode dies and then return.

I restarted 2 host at the same time and when the containers run again, they get a new ip. The problem is that the namemode give a error because it thinks it is another datanode.

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* NameSystem.getDatanode: Data node 10.0.0.13:50010 is attempting to report storage ID 3a7b556f-7364-460e-beac-173132d77503. Node 10.0.0.9:50010 is expected to serve this storage.
```

Is is possible to prevent docker to assign a new ip, and instead keep the last ip after a restart?

Or there are any option for Hadoop config to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Static DHCP addresses for containers accessing an overlay network are officially not supported for the time being, as told here: `https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31860`.

I hope, that docker will provide a solution for this very soon.